# I have 6 days left on my 90 day Schengen. Will I meet with trouble entering Switzerland?

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland, singapore

I hold a Singapore passport and will be travelling from UK (Non-schengen) to Switzerland. I have just 6 days left on my 90 day Schengen visa and intend to stay all 6 days and leave before I become illegal.

My question here is, when I arrive in Zurich, will I meet with any trouble? e.g: need to prove I have a ticket out of the Schengen, prove I'm not intending to over-stay etc?

Comment: Sometimes you will be questioned or you will get a lucky get away. Just make sure that you will leave 1 day before the expiry date, to play safe.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Just to provide a quick update. I managed to enter via Zurich airport with absolutely no trouble at all, no questions asked. Not sure if it's cause I hold a Singaporean passport and if it'll be the same for all other non-EU passports. When I left on the day my Schengen runs out, I also had absolutely no trouble, no questions asked.

Answer (score 3):

There is no formal requirement to hold a ticket to leave the Schengen area but yes, you can be questioned about your intents, and, yes, having something concrete to support your story like a flight reservation might help.